# Template method specialization for multiple types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class “A” which exposes the template method foo.
Foo has a standard implementation which works fine with B,C. It also has a special implementation for D.

```
class A
{
  template<typename T>
  void foo()
  {
    //standard implementation
  }

  template<>
  void foo<D>
  {
    //special implementation
  }
}

class B{};
class C{};
class D{};

int main()
{
  A<B> a1;
  A<C> a2;
  A<D> a3;
}
```

Now, I need to add the class E, which requires for "foo" the same special implementation as D.
Is there a way to say something like: For all the types use the standard foo. For D,E (and so on) the special implementation.

```
class A
{
  template<typename T>
  void foo()
  {
    //standard implementation
  }

  template<>
  void foo<D && E>  <-- PseudoCode - It doesn't work
  {
    //special implementation
  }
}

class B{};
class C{};
class D{};
class E{};

int main()
{
  A<B> a1;
  A<C> a2;
  A<D> a3;
  A<E> a4;
}
```

I was thinking to use the trait classes. But I was hoping there is something simpler to achieve this.
Thanks

Comment: Is there something that make D and E special? ie a member function, a trait

Comment: Yes. They have a member function, let's say  "void bar()", that the others don't have.

Comment: Are the types related; do they have a common base?

Comment: @Jason No they don't.

Comment: How can there be `A<B> a1;`? The `A` class is not templated.

Comment: Yeah I know.. It's not perfect the example. Should be "A a1; a1<B>.foo ();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Walter Brown's  (C++1z) [`void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_bar 
  : std::false_type { };

template <typename T>
struct has_bar<T, void_t<decltype( std::declval<T&>().bar() ) > >
  : std::true_type { };

class A {
  public:
    void foo() { };
};

class B {
  public:
    void bar() { };
};

class C {
  public:
    void bar() { };
};

template <typename T> 
typename std::enable_if<!has_bar<T>::value, void>::type
fun(T t) {
  std::cout << "fun" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_bar<T>::value, void>::type
fun(T t) {
  std::cout << "special fun" << std::endl;
}
```

The code...

```
int main(const int argc, const char* argv[argc]) {

  A a;
  B b;
  C c;

  fun(a);
  fun(b);
  fun(c);

  return 0;
}
```

prints out

```
fun
special fun
special fun
```

Note, that does not check any type semantics, so it may be better declaring `bar()` as an interface and using [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of).

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look on SFINAE to enable and disable function at compile time

If D and E are special, they have let's say the member `void bar()` and not the others, you can actually implement your own type trait:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_bar {
private:
    template<typename C> static std::true_type test(decltype(&C::bar)*);
    template<typename C> static std::false_type test(...);

public:
    constexpr static bool value = decltype(test<T>(nullptr))::value;
};

                     /* false */          /* true */
cout << boolalpha << has_bar<A> << " " << has_bar<E> << endl;
```

Now with this type trait you can use [std::enable_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) as a compile time switch:

```
                                   /* standard if no bar */
template<typename T, typename = enable_if_t< !has_bar<T> >>
void foo()
{
    //standard implementation
}

                                   /* special if bar */
template<<typename T, typename = enable_if_t< has_bar<T> >>
void foo()
{
    //special implementation
}
```

Comment: Fails if `C::bar` is overloaded.  See @Jason's answer for an alternative that just checks that `bar` with no arguments exists.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no way you can do this without defining some [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) machinery. Now the minimum I can think of without including [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header would be the following:

Define "home made "`enable_if` and `is_same` type traits as follows.

```
namespace mine {
  template<bool, typename T = void> struct enable_if {};
  template<typename T> struct enable_if<true, T> { typedef T type; };
  template<typename T, typename U> struct is_same { static bool const value = false; };
  template<typename T> struct is_same<T, T> { static bool const value = true; };
};
```

Apply SFINAE in member function `foo()` of `class A` as follows:

```
class A {
  template<typename T>
  struct pred {
    static bool const value = mine::is_same<T, B>::value || 
    mine::is_same<T, C>::value || mine::is_same<T, D>::value || mine::is_same<T, E>::value;   
  };
public:
  template<typename T> 
  typename mine::enable_if< pred<T>::value, void>::type
  foo() { std::cout << "special implementation"  << std::endl; }

  template<typename T>
  typename mine::enable_if<!pred<T>::value, void>::type
  foo() {std::cout << "standard implementation" << std::endl; }
};
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44cca1ce473a2e65)

P.S the bonus is that the above solution works also for pre C++11 compilers.